Linear page indicator with dots as separators
I am looking for some information, some packages or maybe an idea how to achieve this:

I was searching in pub.dev for packages, something like https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator, but I didn't find anything close to what I want.
Can anyone have any idea how to do this type of page indicator?
